# RVM thinks that ruby is both installed and not installed

Tags: mac, ruby

If I try rvm use  or most other commands that would reference a specific version, it says that the version is not installed. If I try to install it, I am told that it's already installed. Regardless, I can't seem to use any version other than my system default.

I have already tried reinstalling the specific version, reinstalling RVM, and several other potential fixes.

Comment: What do you get from `rvm list` and `rvm info`?

Answer (score 0):

The cause ended up being that my username contained an @, which on Mac messes with rvm. I ended up having to make a new account without the @ and reinstall rvm and everything worked fine.

EDIT: More complete explanation of the issue and solution: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4255